# Decay and Linear ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that a substance decays at a rate proportional to the amount present. Half of the original quantity is left after 1500 yrs. In how many years will the original amount be reduced to 3/4 of the original amount? how much will be left after 2000 yrs?

If D(t) = Ce^kt

$$D(0)= (1/2)D(1500)$$

I found k to equal ln(1/2)/1500

Im stuck on how to find C and the rest. What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the question is about relative amounts, you can set $C=1$.

The given data should translate as $D(1500)=\frac12D(0)$ or $D(0)=\frac12D(-1500)$.

You are asked to solve $D(t)=\frac34D(0)$ and to compute $D(2000)/D(0)$ which should be easy at this point.

Comment: I don't understand why C=1. if the equation is D(t)=Ce^kt how can we say C=1?

Comment: The value of $C=D(0)$ does not matter since all questions are about proportions. Thus $C=100\%=1$ s as useful as any other choice.

Comment: So D(2000) =e^(2000ln(1/2)/1500) ?

Comment: Yes. Or $2^{-2000/1500}=2^{-4/3}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.